# Grouping header elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to group several elements together to make for a header. This can be seen in this link: http://postimg.org/image/l1kikhryn/ 
As you can see, I want to group a set of drop down menus, a picture, and a dropdown menu that is connected to a search bar. I then want to line it up with the block color image behind it.

In the picture everything has its position manually shifted to fit but I would like to clean it up and group them together so they can dynamically size. I am using html and css. Any ideas?

I dont know why this is got a single down vote with no response but it is pretty annoying.

Comment: We can't help without code demonstrating what you've tried. I didn't downvote you, but that's likely the reason why. That being said, perhaps you could implement one of the several responsive UI frameworks which already exist such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)?

Comment: That was very helpful. I am pretty new to this so I figured that including a picture and the general idea would be enough. I believe that I am restricted to using just html and css since the project was given to me with no mention of bootstrap or foundation.

Comment: Both are primarily HTML and CSS frameworks. The Javascript pieces are optional.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a basic HTML/CSS design that mimics the image you linked.  It was good practice for me, so I didn't mind the effort.  This is the [JSFiddle sample I wrote](http://jsfiddle.net/fnC4E/).

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="navbarList">
<li><div class="pictureBox"></div></li>
<li>
    <div class="navButton">
        <select id="firstSelect">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
          <option value="four">four</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li><div class="navButton">
        <select id="firstSelect">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
          <option value="four">four</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li><div class="navButton">
        <select id="firstSelect">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
          <option value="four">four</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li><div class="inputText"><input type="text" name="query" value="search this"></div></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submitButton"></li>
```

This is the CSS:

```
ul#navbarList
{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
width:85%;
margin:35px;
background-color: lightgray;
}

.pictureBox
{
float:left;
overflow:auto;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
background-color:blue;
width: 65px;
height: 85px;
margin: -10px;
}

.navButton
{
float:left;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
background-color:black;
width: 75px;
height: 24px;
margin:20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

select#firstSelect
{
width:75px;
}

.inputText
{
float:left;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
background-color:black;
width: 160px;
height: 25px;
margin:20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

input[name="submitButton"]
{
margin: 25px 0 10px 20px;
}
```

Enjoy!